# PostgreSQL returning duplicate IDs when using IN in a JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with the following information

```
PRODUCTS
id     |description       |featureImage
13     |a phone           | www.image.com/image23
14     |a phone accessory | www.image.com/image24
15     |another accessory | www.image.com/image25


Product Accessories
id     |productId         |accessoryId
1      |13                |14
2      |13                |15
```

When using a query as follows

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (accessories.id, products.description)
        products.description, products.featureImage, accessories.id 
 FROM schema.accessories 
 JOIN schema.products ON products.id IN 
   (SELECT accessories.accessoryId FROM accessories
    WHERE accessories.id IN (14,15))
```

I am getting duplicate results as

```
 description        |featureImage     |id
 a phone accessory  |image.com/image24|14
 a phone accessory  |image.com/image24|15
 another accessory  |image.com/image25|14
 another accessory  |image.com/image25|15
```

The result set I was expecting would be

```
description         |featureImage     |id
a phone accessory   |image.com/image24|14
another accessory   |image.com/image25|15
```

So I would search the table for products with the original product id, and then get the ids of the rows with accessories for that product. Once I get those they are used for the sub query

```
(SELECT accessories.accessoryId FROM accessories WHERE accessories.id IN (14,15))
```

to get the results.

I was thinking that using the DISTINCT ON would stop the duplicates, but I am still getting duplicates, with the id being linked up incorrectly on some of them.

Question is solved, just need to wait for the 8 hours so I can reply and close as answered with the following text;

as per @a_horse_with_no_name by simplifying the query to

```
SELECT p.description, p.featureimage, a.accessory_id
FROM accessories a 
JOIN products p ON p.id = a.accessory_id
```

with a Where statement at the end identifying the proper product to find accessories for, the expected result set is returned.

Comment: So what would I be looking to do if I wanted to only have the product details, with the id of the row in the accessory table for that accessory? So I would only get a single 'a phone accessory' and a single 'another accessory' with the appropriate id for the row containing that product id as the accessory?

Comment: doing `DISTINCT ON (accessories.id)` returns me a result set with the appropriate different ids, but the description, and featureImage both come back as 'phone acessory' with its featureImage url.

Comment: A `distinct on` only makes sense if you also use an `order by`. But your join condition looks pretty strange as well. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I've edited the original question to show the result set I would be looking for.

Comment: Isn't that a simple join between products and accessories based on `accessory.accessoryId = product.id`

Comment: But I can have more than a single accessory id for a product (in this case the phone has 2 accessories, so two ids I need to use)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f460/1

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I guess I was over thinking it again.

Comment: Try with:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accessories.id), products.description, products.featureImage, accessories.id 
 FROM schema.accessories 
 JOIN schema.products ON products.id IN 
(SELECT accessories.accessoryId FROM accessories WHERE accessories.id IN (14,15))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I suggest you post your answer as answer, so we can tick this one off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments it seems all you want is a simple join:

```
SELECT p.description, p.featureimage, a.accessory_id
FROM accessories a 
   JOIN products p ON p.id = a.accessory_id
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f460/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ,p.description
    ,p.featureImage
    ,a.id
FROM SCHEMA.accessories AS a
JOIN SCHEMA.products AS p ON p.id = a.accessoryId
WHERE a.id IN (
        14
        ,15
        )
```

Note, you may have an error in your example: should `WHERE accessories.id IN (14,15)` be `WHERE accessories.accessoryid IN (14,15)`?